# Missing table pubsub_state in ejabberd

Tags: postgresql, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have ejabberd working well but my logs are filling up with references to a missing table pubsub_state.  I have a bunch of other tables with that prefix but not that one.  Where can I find the definition so that I can add it?

I am using PostgreSQL as my back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is in pg.sql but it's strange it wasn't created when you created the other tables...
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/sql/pg.sql#L243

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.

Comment: As I was adding the definition in I noticed there was an empty table named pubsu_state.  Very odd.